# Bitcode Compile During Archive Never Finishes

Tags: ios, archive, bitcode

I am preparing an app for ad hoc distribution via Test Flight.  I have stepped through (successfully) all of the preparatory steps in this Ray Wenderlich article already (https://www.raywenderlich.com/48750/testflight-sdk-tutorial), and I feel confident that the certificate, App ID, and Provisioning Profile are all created correctly and in proper working order.  I am on the step in which you archive the project in Xcode.  I have selected these settings during the archive process:

I choose to Export :

[image]

I choose "Save for Ad Hoc deployment" since our plan is to use Test Flight to distribute the app to our testers.  I *do* believe this is the correct option for that (as opposed to "for enterprise deployment"):

[image]

This is the default setting, and I do not have a specific reason to change it, although I'd appreciate any insight you may have:

[image]

Again, default options for both of these.  The first one is unchecked by default and the second one is checked by default:

[image]

When I get to this screen, the spinner spins seemingly forever:

[image]

The problem seems to be that once it gets to the part where it is compiling from bitcode it spins and spins and shows no signs of finishing.  When I am building the app to run on a device connected to the MBP, it compiles quickly, usually within a few seconds.  What could be causing this unresponsiveness?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I let this run for a long time (basically while I went out shopping).  When I came back it was done.  So for whatever reason this just takes a really long time to do.

That said, it was also the incorrect action.  The way you add testers to TestFlight since Apple bought it is different.  Now, instead of exporting and uploading an IPA file, you have to submit it to the store and let it be reviewed by Apple before you can add testers.

Comment: For me this took about 45 minutes for one .ipa file.

Comment: I just started looking into TestFlight, but I only think the wait period applies to trying to test externally. If you're attempting to test internally, I do not think there will be a review process.

Answer (score 49):

I am facing the same problem. What my suggestion is just enable this check mark when export for iOS App Store Deployment. If you are exporting an adhoc build then do uncheck it. It will work fast.

[image]

Comment: but the app size was very bigger than generating .ipa file from code signing.. what we do for reduce the size?

Comment: This works great! :)
And even that you want to launch the app with bitcode support, you can use this to accelerate your TestFlight, HockeyApp, etc... intermediate test builds.

Answer (score 12):

I have better solution for this problem. Don't go for export option tomato iPA, try out as mentioned below:

1. just right click your Archive and select show in finder
2. Then again right click on resulted file in finder and select show package content
3. then from result open product folder --> Application folder --> and select ".app" file
4. Then simply add this .app file under apps of iTunes software on mac
5. After completing adding process right click on app icon in iTunes
   and show in finder which will give you iPA file.

It would take only 5 minutes max.

Comment: i didn't ask the question

Comment: This worked grate,but is this develpoment ipa or adhoc??

Comment: @ABJ It works for both ipa, development & distribution.

Comment: This will increase the size of IPA file compare to Generated From XCode archive export... Hence Good Solution

Answer (score 1):

One more option is, You have to keep eye on which source code you have is taking small time and get archive process done quickly. So from next time you will have to open this particular source code and perform archive, after that open your working source code and then try archive for that. You will get that done fast for working code as well.

For me, I have kept 2 source code separately.

- One for Xcode 7
- Other for Xcode 8

So whenever I want to create ipa, I open this source code first and make archive then I close this code and perform archive for code I am currently working. This is bit lengthy process but surly it don't take that much of time as well as your system don't get hang.

Answer (score -1):

You can disconnect your wifi wait a few minutes to reconnect again, and then it is ok

Comment: You can also try moving to higher elevation. That usually helps;)