# Xcode takes too much time for compile bit code at time of preparing archive

Tags: xcode, build, bitcode

I am trying to make archive but xcode get stuck at time of compile bitcode.
what i have to do? Enable bitcode or disable?

Comment: It would be easier for us to help you if you gives us more informations on the context.

Comment: Same issue after updating to xcode 7.3, i get stuck too on bitcode compile. i uncheck this and now i get archived. is there any issue if i uncheck bitcode?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Impact of Xcode build options "Enable bitcode" Yes/No](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31088618/impact-of-xcode-build-options-enable-bitcode-yes-no)

Comment: See this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41362836/532756), hope it will help you

Answer (score 14):

I was facing the same problem. What my suggestion is just enable this check mark when export for iOS App Store Deployment. If you are exporting an adhoc build then do uncheck it. It will work fast.

**Bitcode refers to to the type of code: "LLVM Bitcode" that is sent to iTunes Connect. This allows Apple to use certain calculations to re-optimize apps further (e.g: possibly downsize executable sizes). If Apple needs to alter your executable then they can do this without a new build being uploaded**

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the explanation on bitcode. I was wondering if I should leave compileBitcode on when making a build for HockeyApp via xcodebuild. Definitely don't need bitcode for HockeyApp, and it builds much faster.

Answer (score 13):

I have a better solution for this problem. Don't go for the export option tomato iPA, try out as mentioned below:

1. Right click your Archive and select "Show" in Finder
2. Then again right click on the resulted file in Finder and select "Show Package Contents"
3. Then from the result open the product folder --> Application folder --> and
   select the ".app" file
4. Then simply add this .app file under apps of iTunes software on Mac
5. After completing the adding process right click on the app icon in iTunes
   and show in Finder, which will give you the iPA file.

Comment: Have you seen the size of IPA file after doing this? That is 3 times bigger than normal archiving. I don't know why? can you please tell me?

Comment: Yet I don't came across such increase in size. But you can try out copy png option in Xcode which will help to minimise IPA size.

Comment: @iOSGeek It works for both development as well as for production. You can upload production build using application loader. Only swift code builds need to upload through Organiser as so it don't work for swim code production build